# Integration with Probability Density Function

Tags: matlab, probability

I need to plot the probability density function {p(z,phi)}and need to integrate it,as shown in the attached eq.#1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsJwc.jpg)
where Af and Vf are constants,
      phi is angle,
      z is distance(numerical value, can be in decimals)

The P(z,phi) will be the force values along with respective different values of z and phi.
Could someone guide me, on MATLAB, how can I write these set of equations?

Answer (score 0):

To intregate your function, you should either create an m-file or anonymous function

f = @(z,phi) P(z,phi) * p(z,phi)

where you construct P and p similarly. Then you will need to use one of the numerical integrators, such as ode45 to integrate f twice... once over f and once over phi.

Comment: I still could not get how to write for the probability density function along with the given ranges and then integrate it twice as you have suggested

Comment: If I break down my question in to parts then it may be easier to answer. How can I solve probability distribution function of two variables with in a given range? As shown below;

p(a,b)=p(a)p(b)
where,
            p(a,b) is a probability distribution function
            p(a)= 1/c   -c/2<a<c/2
            c is any constant value
and,    p(b)=sin(b)                    0<b<pi/2

Comment: I have tried to write down the probability function for the above mentioned equations #2 to equation#4. Please help me correct my code. 
%For p(z)
Lf=2;
z=-Lf/2:0.1:Lf/2;
X=unifpdf(1/Lf,-Lf/2,Lf/2)

%For p(phi)
phi=0:0.1:pi/2; % 0<phi<pi/2
Y=unifpdf(sin(phi),0,pi/2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you multiply a uniform probability distribution between -lf/2 and lf/2 with another probability distribution that looks like the first quarter of a sine wave. You want to know the resulting probability distribution.

Basically if lf/2 > pi/2 you end up with the same distribution. The sine-distribution is entirely inside the uniform distribution. If (lf/2)<(pi/2) the uniform-distribution chops of part of your sine-distribution. You then want to divide your probability distribution by the part you choped off so the integral stays one. It must remain a probability distribution.

The integral of sin(x) is cos(x). So in that case you devide by (1-cos(lf/2))

Below is a script that makes it more visible:

```
lf=2;
xx = linspace(-lf,lf,1E4);
p1 = (xx>-lf/2&xx<lf/2)*(1/lf);
p2 = zeros(size(xx));
p2(xx>0&xx<pi/2) = sin(xx(xx>0&xx<pi/2));

p3 = p2.*p1.*lf;
if lf<pi
    p3 = p3./(1-cos(lf/2));
end
plot(xx,p1,xx,p2,xx,p3)
legend({'uniform distribution','sine','result'})
%integrals (actually Riemann sums):
sum(p1.*(xx(2)-xx(1)))
sum(p2.*(xx(2)-xx(1)))
sum(p3.*(xx(2)-xx(1)))
```